# How can I remove my data but keep the OS when putting my MacBook up for sale?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to delete items off MacBook but leave the Mountain Lion OS. How can I do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a link to Apple's directions on how to erase and reinstall OS X Mountain Lion, so it will be like new.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph11273)

Comment: I cannot type a name in the box. The format is highlighted Mac OS Extended (journaled) so I am not allowed to do anything here. I cannot erase!!! Why

Comment: @DMitch Please ask a new question describing what you are trying to do and where you run into problems with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to leave the installed applications on the unit, you could create a new "admin" user, log in as that new "admin," delete your original user (and choose to delete the home folder).

For security reasons, it might be a good idea to [erase free space](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3680) on the drive before you sell it (so that someone with a little skill doesn't piece your data back together).